# How to define a numerical function which maps function to function?

Tags: function-construction

For iterative **numerical** application (for example NestList) I need to define a function, which depends on a function  and outputs a function.

To describe the problem, here I give a simple example:

```
pint = Function[{ip }, Function[{t}, Integrate[(x + t x - 2 t) ip[x], {x, 0, t} ] ]];
```

This analytical function might be applied iteratively as expected

```
pint[Exp[-#]&][t] (*1 - t - E^-t (1 + t^2)*)
pint[pint[Exp[-#] &]][t] (*-9 - t + 1/2 (-3 + t) t^2 + E^-t (9 + 10 t + 7 t^2 + 3 t^3 + t^4)*)
```

Works fine, syntax seems to be ok.

Now my real problem, thereby I assume the integration can't be evaluated analytically:

Simply changing `Integrate` to `NIntegrate` gives

```
pintN = Function[{ip },Function[{t}, NIntegrate[(x + t x - 2 t) ip[x], {x, 0, t} ] ]] ;
```

which evaluates as expected (same result as pint)

```
Plot[{pint[Exp[-#] &][u], pintN[Exp[-#] &][u]}, {u, 0, 5},PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.01], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Unfortunately the function `pintN` can't be applied iteratively!
For example

```
Plot[pintN[pintN[Exp[-#] &]][u], {u, 0, 5}]
```

doesn't work!

How can I make the numerical version run?
Thanks!

Comment: I think `pintN = Function[{ip}, Function[{t}, Module[{x}, Quiet@NIntegrate[(x + t x - 2 t) ip[x], {x, 0, t}]]]]` works to make the integration variable unique. `NIntegrate` splutters some messages (hence the `Quiet`), but I think the answer is correct. Note that `pint` also seems to suffer from localizations issues with `x`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks, I tried your modified definition but `Plot[Evaluate[pintN[pintN[Exp[-#] &]][t]] , {t, 0, Pi}]` doesn't finish evaluation.

Comment: Ah, but that's because it makes no sense to evaluate a numerical function with at symbolic symbol `t`, right? You'll need some form of pattern matching to handle that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With numerical functions, you have to be careful that `NIntegrate` will always get a valid integrand. The easiest way to do this is with pattern matching:

```
ClearAll[pintN];
pintN[ip_][t_?NumericQ] := Module[{x},
  NIntegrate[(x + t x - 2 t) ip[x], {x, 0, t}]
]
```

This will now work, but it's very slow:

```
Plot[pintN[pintN[Exp[-#] &]][u], {u, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

Note that sometimes you can cleverly use `ParametricNDSolveValue` to represent integrals. For example, to represent a function that numerically integrates another function you can use:

```
int[f_] := Module[{x, y, t},
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {y'[x] == f[x], y[0] == 0},
   y[t],
   {x, 0, t},
   t
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I learned  how to restrict `t_?NumericQ`in the definition of `pintN`. It seems to be impossible to restrict t in my original defintion `Function[{ip },Function[{t}…` Thanks also for your hint concerning `NDSolve`  .